# How can I get the sensitivity of some eye cone at a specific wavelength?

Tags: visible-light, biophysics, vision

The following graph shows the sensitivity for eye cones and rods, but I want to know e.g. what is the red cone sensitivity for a wavelength of 500 nm?

How can I find an answer for questions like this?

[image: A graph of wavelengths and eye sensitivity]

Comment: You read it from the graph, right? Find 500 nm on the x-axis, draw a  vertical line at that point, find the height of the red curve on that vertical line, and read on the y-axis what the sensitivity is. Don't expect any natural exact analytic formula. But you may find functions that fit the graphs rather well.

Comment: That formula is what I'm looking for Luboš Motl

Comment: Well, if you were rational, you wouldn't be. Cones and rods are extremely complex objects.

Comment: @LubošMotl I mean a function that fits the graphs.

Comment: Just use a polynomial times a Gaussian and adjust the coefficients. Or try something else. None of these options will be dramatically more convenient than others. I already told you about thrice that there is no "the formula".

Answer (score 1):

See the [CIE 1931 color space](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CIE_1931_color_space), it is based on the sensitivity of the cones. You can find standards and tabels on the site of [The Colour & Vision Research laboratory and database](http://cvrl.ioo.ucl.ac.uk/index.htm). The functions can be downloaded in cvs, xml, tabular or plot format, with stepsize of 0.1 nm, 1 nm or 5 nm.
No mathematical formula, but a lookup or a formula doesn't make much difference when used in a program (unless you hoped for a useful formula like a normal distribution. No such luck I'm afraid)..

[This pdf](https://www.ecse.rpi.edu/~schubert/Light-Emitting-Diodes-dot-org/Sample-Chapter.pdf) has some more info.